# wait() won't hold the progress of the application

Tags: java, android, performance, time

My issue is that the appending the value of "val" which is passed to the method that contains the wait() call doesn't happen in intervals. I would appreciate it if someone can actually fix this.

I have tried handler.postDelay(){} and that doesn't seem to help either, if i'm asking it to wait for one second, it will stay for five seconds or even less and append the 10 digits value I'm trying to append in intervals. For example, if I have "123456" it should print "1" then wait for 1 second, print "2" and so on.

```
public void appendData(val){
logs.append(String.valueOf(val));
//This is what I'm using to start the waiting period
synchronized (this) {
  try {
    this.wait(1000);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```

I Can not figure it out whatever I change or make, it will always not wait, and at the end appends the whole number, or to be exact the whole number appears in frot of me on the UI at once, it doesn't happen on intervals as I want to be.

Comment: Are you confusing wait (for a notification) and sleep (for a specified time)?

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, I want the thread to stop for one second

Comment: Then you want ```Thread.sleep(1000)```.  ```obj.wait(1000)``` means wait until something calls ```obj.notify()``` but do not wait more than 1 second.  If you wake early it seems that it implies something's calling ```notify```, but perhaps that's inherent in the Android framework, about which I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        System.out.print(1);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(2);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(3);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(4);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.print(5);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.println(6);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

As has been said in the comments `wait` is for synchronization between multiple threads (it is also low-level for that purpose; usually you would want to use one of the higher-level tools in `java.util.concurrent`, for example).

Rather than always specifying the waiting time in milliseconds I prefer to use the `TimeUnit` enum to specify it in a more human-friendly unit suitable for the amount of time to wait.

Why have I put `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` there? For the correct way to handle the `InterruptedException` that may be thrown from sleeping read about [*The Law of the Sabotaged Doorbell* here](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html). Both informative and entertaining.